# Why does the Desktop Dungeons beta freeze my computer?

Tags: technical-issues, desktop-dungeons

I am trying to play the Desktop Dungeons beta, but every time I try, my entire computer just freezes up, and I can't do anything (short of physically turning it off and on again).

I don't know if it is a problem with the Unity plugin, or my browser (I am using Chrome), or my laptop.

Some basic info about the laptop:

It's a VAIO with a AMD Dual-Core E-350 CPU, and a AMD Mobility Radeon HD 6310 video card. It has 2 GB of RAM, and is running Windows 7 Home Premium (32 bit). The rest of the specs can be found [here](http://www.bestbuy.ca/catalog/productdetails.aspx?sku=10163870).

Is there a way for me to be able to play the beta on this laptop?

Comment: I don't think its Chrome, I play on Chrome regularly, and have had fewer crashes with it than with IE9.  At what point does it freeze?  Do you get to the login prompt?

Comment: @bwarner It freezes while Unity is loading. I never even get to the login.

Comment: Have you tried disabling anti-virus programs before launching?  See http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/78979-Anti-virus-problems

Comment: @bwarner Tried that, and the only thing that changes is that I now get a message saying "The following plug-in is unresponsive: "Unity Player".